# QProcess setStandardOutputFile to nullDevice does not work (win)

Tags: qt, stdout, qprocess

I have a QProcess where I am not able to discard the Output on a Windows Machine:

```
QProcess * pingProcess = new QProcess;

arguments "google.com" << "-n" << "1";

pingProcess->setStandardOutputFile(pingProcess->nullDevice());
pingProcess->setStandardErrorFile(pingProcess->nullDevice());
pingProcess->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::SeparateChannels); 

int exitCode = pingProcess->execute("ping",arguments);
```

I still have the Output of the ping in the command line

Any idea?

Comment: You're running the executable by calling [`QProcess::execute`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute).  That's a `static` member and its behaviour is probably unaffected by any previous calls to `QProcess::setStandardOutputFile` etc.  Try running the executable using [`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start-1) instead, i.e.`pingProcess->start("ping", arguments)`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. I just had to add a callback to retrieve the exit code. 
  connect(pingProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )), this, 
  SLOT(ping_process_cb(int , QProcess::ExitStatus )));